# How to convert an ascii number into the appropiate character and assign it to a string

Tags: c++, c++11

I am currently attempting to read through a string. Each character is run through a series of "if/else if" tests. If the current character meets one of the conditions, it is added to a different string (and sometimes other actions are done as well). My problem is that when the character is added to a different string it is obviously a number and not the original character (example: '+' is saved as '43'). How does one solve this issue? Everything I found was converting to ASCII, I need to convert back from it (I think).

Code (rather large: I'm a novice):

```
string Input = RemoveChar(s, ' ');
vector< vector<string> > Vector = vector< vector<string> >();
char LastChar = ' ';
string str = "";
vector<string> temp = vector<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < Input.length(); i++)
{
    char c = Input[i];
    if ((i == 0) && (c == '-'))
        str += c;
    else if ((isOperator(LastChar)) && (c == '-'))
        str += c;
    else if (isOperator(c))
    {
        temp.push_back(str);
        temp.push_back(to_string(c));
        Vector.push_back(temp);
        temp.clear();
        str.erase();
    }
    else if (isDouble(c))
        str += c;
    if (i == (Input.length() - 1))
    {
        temp.push_back(str);
        temp.push_back("");
        Vector.push_back(temp);
    }
    LastChar = c;
}
```

Comment: Any particular code posting site to use?

Comment: Cut'n'paste to here will do

Comment: This the Q&A site. You can just ask a question about the code you show. There's a button to format it as code. The code should be short enough.

Comment: Some pointers on asking a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Copy/paste your code into your question here and format it. Everything related to your question needs to be *here*, in the question itself.

Comment: Okay. What is `isDouble`? Can you show it? Also, supply a sample input + goal

Comment: It is a function that error checks a string to make sure it can appropriately be converted into a floating-point number. It will give user (through console screen) detailed error messages. Rather large function to be honest. Overall: makes sure each character in string is either a digit, a '-', or a '.'

Comment: How can it be, if it takes a character only?

Comment: `(c == 0) && (c == '-')` is always false.

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes one receives a string the other receives a character (different parameter types). My bad. It does same thing, just to the one character

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah, unfound bug. first c should be i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do

```
std::string c_as_a_str(1, c);
```

instead of `to_string(c)` which will treat `c` as a "number" - an integral type, which `char` happens to be in C and C++

**EDIT** By the way, it's the constructor number (2) from the docs: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: Added a helpful [documentation link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) so you know how to find out things for yourself later.

Comment: Thank you, precisely what I needed!

Comment: There a lot more things to say about it, but I guess, one thing at a time! Considering hitting [CodeReview.SE] when you're done. People will tell you what ---stinks--- can be done more elegantly :)

Comment: I believe if I did that, I'd feel about 10x smaller than I already do lol, but I will